# How to handle NAs while assigning values

Tags: r

I have a data frame `x` which includes two variables `fdhm1` and `fdhm2`. Now, I want to generate a new variable `fdhm` conditional on both values of `fdhm1` and `fdhm2`.

Specifically, if `fdhm1 != NA`  and `fdhm2 ==0`, `fdhm <- fdhm1`. Otherwise, `fdhm <- NA`.

Here is my codes:

```
fdhm   <- NA
x   <- cbind(x,fdhm)
use   <- x$fdhm1 != NA & x$fdhm2 == 0
x$fdhm[use]   <- x$fdhm1[use]
```

but an error message popped up, saying that **NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments**

I am not sure what the reason is?

Comment: I have solved it by re-writing the condition ```use <- x$fdhm2 == 0 & !is.na(x$fdhm2)  &  !is.na(x$fdhm1)```

Comment: Shouldn't be the condition asking `!NA` before `== 0` like `use <- !is.na(x$fdhm2) & x$fdhm2 == 0 & !is.na(x$fdhm1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `!is.na(x$fdhm1)` (rather than `x$fdhm1 != NA`), e.g.,

```
x <- within(x,fdhm <- ifelse(!is.na(fdhm1)&fdhm2==0,fdhm1,NA))
```

---

Here is an example showing you what happened.

Given a vector `u` like below

```
> u
[1] NA  2 NA  1 NA
```

then

```
> u!=NA
[1] NA NA NA NA NA

> !is.na(u)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Since `NA` represents a missing value, logical operations involving `NA` are often hardcoded to return `NA` and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.